# How can I join 2 data sets?

Tags: java, oracle, oracle11g

I am developing a distributed system application where there are four separate entities. They all have four separate databases. I have set up a RMI structure but now I want to implement methods to retrieve data from say more than one table. Because of the previously stated scenario of the entities having separate databases joins cannot be used. For example suppose Entity 1 has a table called education and Entity 2 has a table called Criminals. Now I want to get all criminals who are educated. How could I implement a method to do this as joins cannot be used?

Comment: Maybe dblink is what you are looking for.

Comment: This is a standard question - the standard answer is "use the set operators" - UNION, MINUS, and INTERSECT. Best of luck.

Comment: Your actual question had nothing to do with RMI. Don't tag indiscriminately.